# Docusign : How to send confirmation email with link to embedded signer

Tags: docusignapi

I am using the DocuSign API in an embedded manner. I create an envelope and add signers, the first signer always being set as embedded. This allows me to retrieve a URL that is then embedded in an iframe.

However, I also wish, to trigger an email (as soon as the envelope has been created, NOT upon completion) that gets sent to the primary recipient/signer as if they were a nonembedded signer.

I tried adding the signer twice, with the same role, to the recipients, but that didn't work.  No email was sent.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a setting to enable this but that it needs to be enabled by someone on DocuSign's side, like your account manager.  If you do not have an account manager yet please respond to the auto-generated emails that were sent out to you once you created your account, you should have 3 of them.

Answer (score 0):

The account settings available are only for Completion emails.  However, the REST API also supports an `embeddedRecipientStartURL` parameter on the signer object that triggers a normal DocuSign email.  The value of this parameter is the URL that should be included in the email.  This means you can link back to your own application and request the recipient view as normal.

Check here for more detail: [Signer embeddedRecipientStartURL](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Recipients/Signers%20Recipient.htm?Highlight=embeddedRecipientStartURL).  Note: if you set this to a value of "SIGN_AT_DOCUSIGN" then DocuSign will provide its own URL and take care of signing.  The trade-off is that you won't be able to initiate any bespoke authentication you are doing in your own application.